# UITableViewDiffableDataSource: how to get a section index

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios13

I'm trying to adopt the new iOS 13 UITableViewDiffableDataSource and I've hit a snag; I can't work how to implement

```
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]?
```

That's a data source method, not a delegate method. So, now that the data source is the UITableViewDiffableDataSource, it needs to implement that method. But it doesn't.

I tried subclassing UITableViewDiffableDataSource and adding an implementation of `sectionIndexTitles`, but my implementation was never called:

```
class MyDataSource : UITableViewDiffableDataSource<String,String> {
    func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return self.snapshot().sectionIdentifiers // not called
    }
}
```

Has anyone solved this one? I'll file it as a bug just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to subclass `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` and then overwrite

```
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView)
```

by yourself.

To enable the index' functionality though, you have to also overwrite

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int)
```

Here is an example how I implemented it:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class TableViewDiffableDataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<String, MPMediaItemCollection> {
    var sectionTitles = [String]()

    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return sectionTitles
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionTitles[section]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        return sectionTitles.firstIndex(of: title) ?? 0
    }
}
```

[Credits go to Steve Breen, who led me in the right direction.](https://twitter.com/__breeno/status/1164980247944503297?s=20)

Answer (score 0):

After you init `self.dataSource` to `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` (which sets itself to the `tableView.dataSource`) set the `tableView.dataSource` back to self, i.e. the `UITableViewController` subclass. Now in your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods forward those to `self.dataSource` and return its info (this is the composition pattern). Now your `UITableViewController` just implements its section titles as normal since it is the table's data source.

I believe `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` should not be setting itself as the dataSource if one is already set but I guess they designed it to work in the least error prone way because with `UITableViewController` added to a storyboard it's set as the `dataSource` and `delegate` by default.